# CSS: Div to auto fit to bottom of the page for all screen sizes

Tags: css

Basically I have something like this at the moment:-

[image]

The black rectangle is the div element I would like to extend to the bottom of the page so it will be at the bottom no matter which screen resolution you are using. The black background div will be replaced with an image (so if possible I don't want the image to be distorted.)

At the moment the code I have is:-

HTML

```
<div id="main-container" class="container">

    <img style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://url.com/test.jpg" alt="" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-37" />

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-container {
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: #000;
}

.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

And then I am using bootstrap which contains all the CSS for the max-width.

```
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
```

At the moment, the image goes past the bottom of the page but I want to contain in within the bottom of the browser. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position and also height & width:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with CSS. You need to use Javascript to dynamically modify the CSS for what it detects. I use something like this:

```
function setSizes() {
    "use strict";
    var height = ($(window).height() - $("#top").height()) - 5,
        fancytree_padding_text = $(".fancytree-container").css("padding-top"),
        get_padding = new RegExp("(.*?)(px)"),
        fancytree_padding = parseInt(get_padding.exec(fancytree_padding_text)[0], 10);
    $(".fancytree-container").css("max-height", (height - (fancytree_padding * 2) - 5) + "px");
    $(".feeds").css("max-height", height + "px");
    $(".details").css("max-height", height + "px");
    $(".bottomPadding").css("padding-top", (height - ($(".bottomPadding p").height() + 55)) + "px");
setFeedWidths();
}
```

I also add code to listen for resizing and call this when the document loads:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    setSizes();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        setSizes();
    });
}
```

Comment: What's with the down vote? I have never found a straight CSS answer to this. And the code above works for me. So what gives?